# Low Entropy Literature

Tags: code-golf, kolmogorov-complexity

This is one of my favourite poems I wanted to share. Especially because it looks good for compressing. Who cares about literature in the 21st century anyway.

## Goal

Your goal is to write the **shortest program** possible that prints out the following poem:
 http://pastebin.com/aXV0C515

## Rules

- The HQ9Monkey++ language is **prohibited**

Comment: This doesn't seem too different from the other kolmogorov-complexity questions, I'm afraid.

Comment: So just downloading that text is permitted?

Comment: @AdamSpeight that would be a standard loophole. So, no.

Comment: Doesn't say that in the rules.

Comment: @JanDvorak many don't seem too different from printing hello world somehow tricky. so we just... wait and maybe no one is interested and that would prove your point.

Comment: If you give an infinite number of monkeys an infinite number of typewriters...

Comment: @PeterTaylor Ah, you're right. I couldn't find it so I took it as It didn't even happen.

Answer (score 6):

## Python 2.x (Baseline answer, <s>651</s> 650, +/- 40% gain)

```
print'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'.decode('base64').decode('zip')
```

Comment: doesn't work in python3

Comment: @Pinna_be It would cost 2 more bytes (I just noticed I have an extra whitespace). If you'd convert the `print` to a Python 3 `print`, it would work.

Comment: Huh? Python's strings have decode-function? Funny because I primarily work with Python and never knew about that.

Comment: @TheRare Neat, huh?

Comment: @Synthetica Indeed.

Comment: @TheRare (There's also an `encode` method, which I used to generate this code, just an fyi)

Comment: @Synthetica Yes, about that one I knew. :)

Answer (score 3):

## Bash, 499 bytes

Why wasn't this a standard loophole?

```
0000000: 7461 696c 202d 6334 3733 2022 2430 227c  tail -c473 "$0"|
0000010: 7a63 6174 3b65 7869 740a 1f8b 0800 5d28  zcat;exit.....](
0000020: a753 0003 4d53 5176 8430 08fc cf29 b81a  .S..MSQv.0...)..
0000030: 2a9a bc26 6049 529f 3d7d 27ae 6ef7 2fc2  *..&`IR.=}'.n./.
0000040: 00c3 3056 d6c5 9c0e 3197 4ac5 f44b ce8c  ..0V....1.J..K..
0000050: 5808 1669 4566 65b7 75fd cc78 dae5 fe9e  X..iEfe.u..x....
0000060: 5c78 2153 9ad8 269e 6a40 9e5a 143a 121e  \x!S..&.j@.Z.:..
0000070: b579 2f95 acb7 1bde ba4a 0dab 5bb9 0303  .y/......J..[...
0000080: 66c7 d38c bd06 0aaf 8f28 6e20 e4a9 0a8d  f........(n ....
0000090: a66b da62 0b49 6fec 9a24 2f57 e2f5 5dbf  .k.b.Io..$/W..].
00000a0: 3bbb 848f 002b 37f3 0402 21f2 cf43 78e7  ;....+7...!..Cx.
00000b0: 9644 5ba5 d9cf a4db e08a b267 e896 3c3f  .D[........g..<?
00000c0: 54b9 8f81 856b 137f 84e1 bc47 9ea4 05f9  T....k.....G....
00000d0: 490f 9076 ebba 548a a9a2 9bf3 a161 1569  I..v..T......a.i
00000e0: f4a6 ba63 0728 74a2 ec99 5352 ce04 bc0a  ...c.(t...SR....
00000f0: 7b3e a9f0 2201 31ec 6b8f d285 4f53 65ac  {>..".1.k...OSe.
0000100: 1f20 9282 2b80 5dc7 9ba7 fc0e 3ee8 2137  . ..+.].....>.!7
0000110: 4295 76bf 6a9e 495f 0363 6f2a 86ca c8ce  B.v.j.I_.co*....
0000120: ba75 a9d7 a166 b763 f927 db6c a4de 3780  .u...f.c.'.l..7.
0000130: 704a b395 0136 aa78 bc53 d860 d8a3 45c3  pJ...6.x.S.`..E.
0000140: 85a0 80a9 04c8 35f3 7717 daa0 7cce 4c73  ......5.w...|.Ls
0000150: 4c65 67fd 1509 b087 8188 5dc3 1b2b 09cf  Leg.......]..+..
0000160: 9126 81c0 61b8 e8a5 e0ab bbca 516b 1c2a  .&..a.......Qk.*
0000170: 720b 83a5 603d 4873 95b4 23e5 6106 72d9  r...`=Hs..#.a.r.
0000180: 4731 a468 f1b9 7adf 7771 2a52 4000 561b  G1.h..z.wq*R@.V.
0000190: b5af 0c4c 18a3 7570 8527 a721 751c d6b8  ...L..up.'.!u...
00001a0: cb0e 5e16 e0e1 58f6 3656 2dec 7384 d3c7  ..^...X.6V-.s...
00001b0: 9cd6 5d29 cb7a bf2a dae4 0553 d8d1 e0ff  ..]).z.*...S....
00001c0: a209 b527 ad57 0d36 5ab3 cc4d 2e69 2fda  ...'.W.6Z..M.i/.
00001d0: b76f 7996 4fc2 5b57 fa30 756d 1f94 2b1d  .oy.O.[W.0um..+.
00001e0: e6f9 fe9f aed7 2174 35f8 03f5 2b98 87b5  ......!t5...+...
00001f0: 0300 00                                  ...
```

base64:

```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```

Comment: I see what you did there... I was messing around with the same in Python, but it didn't work out for me.